# What do you call a javelin thrower?

Tags: terminology, track-and-field

Is there a name for a javelin thrower?  in baseball we've got pitcher, batter etc.

Comment: As the answers indicate, there's no accepted specific term, but you may find some sportswriters fond of florid prose who invent colorful phrases like "spear men" and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Like Philip Kendall said, in athletics, a person who throws a javelin is called a "javelin thrower".  [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/javelin-thrower) has an entry for "javelin thrower":

> (athletics) a person who throws a javelin

There is the word "javelinier" (or "javelineer"), but apparently that is only used for non-athletic purposes.  [Wikitionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/javelinier) defines "javelinier" as:

> A soldier who throws a javelin

There used to be the word "jaculator", which is defined in [*The Century dictionary and cyclopedia*](http://=PA3213&lpg=PA3213#v=onepage&q&f=false) (published in 1906) as "one who throws (a javelin)":

[image]

There is even an entry in [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/jaculator) which has the same definition for "jaculator", but I'm fairly certain that word isn't used nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a more specific term than "javelin thrower". Certainly that's what Wikipedia uses to describe eg [Jan Železný](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_%C5%BDelezn%C3%BD):

> Jan Železný [...] is a Czech javelin thrower